# CONNECT Proxy over Squid with TLS termination

Tags: ssl, proxy, squid, lets-encrypt

I can create a regular http(s) proxy with Squid, which can then be accessed at **http**://my-ip.

I want to have TLS termination, so I can access **httpS**://my-domain.

I have generated ssl certs using certbot over nginx and then reused those files as:

```
https_proxy 443 tls-cert=/path/fullchain.pem tls-key=/path/privkey.pem
```

However running:

```
$ curl -x httpS://my-domain google.com
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

What is needed to to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** solution for chain issue, compile squid from source with `--with-gnutls` or `--with-openssl`.

--

For some reason, chain of certificates generated by Let's Encrypt are not in default CAfile.

You can suppress the error with `--proxy-insecure` or use `--proxy-cacert /path/fullchain.pem`.